# Sending a http request with METHOD=HEAD

Tags: python, mechanize

I would like to send a http request with METHOD=HEAD using python 2. In mechanize there is a nice function called mechanize.Request. Unfortunately i only can set METHOD to either GET or POST but nothing else. Do you know whether there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import urllib2

class RequestWithMethod(urllib2.Request):
  def __init__(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    self._method = method
    urllib2.Request.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def get_method(self):
    return self._method
```

Then do something like this:

```
  request = RequestWithMethod("HEAD", "%s" % url)
```